# this 4sum LEETCODE c++ code RUNTIME ERROR

Tags: c++, runtime-error

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> fourSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<vector<int>> ans; 
        sort(begin(nums),end(nums));
        int n = nums.size();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            vector<int> v ;
            for(int j = i+1 ; j< n ; j++)
           {    
                int start = j+1 , end = n-1 ;
            while(start<end){
                int t = nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[start]+nums[end];
                if(t==target){
                    v={nums[i],nums[j],nums[start],nums[end]};
                    ans.push_back(v);
                   start++;end--;
                }
               else if(t<target){
                    start++;
                }
                else{end--;}
            }
           }
        }
        sort(begin(ans),end(ans)); 
        n = ans.size();
            vector<vector<int>> ans2;
        ans2.push_back(ans[0]);
        for(int i = 1 ; i < n ;i++){
            if( ans[i]==ans[i-1]){}
            else{
                ans2.push_back(ans[i]);
            }
        }
        return ans2 ;
    }
};
```

why this code give runtime error in following testcase

[-2,2,5,9,3,4,7,1,0,-1,-2,2,5,9,3,4,7,1,0,-1,-2,2,5,9,3,4,7,1,0,-1,-2,2,5,9,3,4,7,1,0,-1,-2,2,5,9,3,4,7,1,0,-1,-2,2,5,9,3,4,7,1,0,-1,-2,2,5,9,3,4,7,1,0,-1,-2,2,5,9,3,4,7]

500

question Link :- https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/

Comment: When `ans` is empty, when you `ans2.push_back(ans[0]);` then bad things happen.

Comment: @Eljay thank you so much ...